# How to open Pydev Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse, pydev

so I guess this quest is kind of stupid, but I am completely new to eclipse and pydev. I recently switched from using [SPE](http://pythonide.stani.be/). So I closed the Pydev Package explorer, how do I open it again? I am using LiClipse 0.9.7. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see what you see, but try...

Window | Show View | Other... | Pydev Package Explorer

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the package explorer is gone, is there anything else i can try?
Edit, I opened the Java Package Explorer instead (while in PyDev view), it worked

Answer (score 3):

@Grzegorz Oledzki is right, but I wanted to add some more info:

If you're in the PyDev perspective (window > open perspective > pydev), you can use Shift+Alt+W when you're inside any editor and then select to show that editor in the pydev package explorer (this also works to show in other places such as the outline and it's very handy to go from the editor to the pydev package explorer).

Also, in the latest version (3.3.3), you can use Ctrl+3 and then write 'pydev package explorer' to go to it (actually, it'll show much earlier to select and that can be used to go to any view or preferences page or even to activate some menu).

Note: this would also work on earlier versions if the Ctrl+3 binding that did a comment in the PyDev editor was removed (to let the default Ctrl+3 from Eclipse do its work).